# Qual o real conceito e utilidade de classes POCO?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, classes, modelagem, poco

Estou estudando e desenvolvendo um novo projeto e a pouco estudando sobre Windows Phone 7.1, vi que eles sugerem/indicam o uso de classes **POCO**, para mapeamento de banco de dados (Parece-me que o Windows Phone 7.1 utiliza de alguma versão compact do EF (Entity Framework)), não cheguei a estudar muito a fundo o caso do Windows Phone, pois este ainda não é o momento de estudar isso a fundo, só estudei o básico para entender seus conceitos.

Mas o que gostaria de entender melhor é:

1. O porque da utilização de classes POCO?
2. Qual a vantagem que isso pode trazer?
3. O porque de isso ser empregado em um Projeto?
4. E o que é de fato classes POCO? (Conceitualmente falando)

Comment: Se o @brasofilo estivesse lendo isso eu ia dizer pra ele que eu não respondi pq entendo **poco** do assunto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1. O porque da utilização de classes POCO?

Um objeto POCO não tem qualquer dependência com um *framework* externo.

`Exemplo:` Em minha camada de negócio, crio objetos POCO para que essa camada não tenha 
dependência a tecnologias e *frameworks* externos. Assim, posso trocar de tecnologias e/ou
frameworks sem mexer na minha camada de negócios (que é o "coração" do software).

> 2. Qual a vantagem que isso pode trazer?

- Minimiza a dependência entre as camadas.
- Minimiza a manutenção, caso eu troque de tecnologias e/ou *frameworks* apenas as camadas de infra-estrutura são afetadas.
- Aumenta sua capacidade de teste.

> 3. O porque de isso ser empregado em um Projeto?

Acredito que dados os benefícios citados nas demais respostas é interessante a utilização.

> 4. E o que é de fato classes POCO? (Conceitualmente falando)

"Plain Old CLR Object"

Uma classe sem atributos que descrevem as preocupações de infra-estrutura, *frameworks* externos ou outras responsabilidades que seus objetos de domínio não deve ter.

**Exemplos:**

1. Estamos amarrados ao *Entity Framework* se deixarmos ele criar
   nossas classes de entidades assim:

```cs
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="SistemaOS.Model", Name="Pessoas")]
[Serializable()]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class Pessoas : EntityObject
{
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 id_pessoa
    {
        get
        {
            return _id_pessoa;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id_pessoa != value)
            {
                Onid_pessoaChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("id_pessoa");
                _id_pessoa = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value,"id_pessoa");
                ReportPropertyChanged("id_pessoa");
                Onid_pessoaChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Um exemplo simples de classe [POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object):

```cs
//Ao trocar meu framework de persistência eu não precisarei mexer nessa classe de negócio
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    public int Cpf { get; set; }

    public string NomeCompleto()
    {
        return Nome + " " + Sobrenome;
    }
}
```

Comment: Então as classes POCO, são classes livres de dependências. Certo? São similares a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) então? Qual é a diferença? (Talvez isso já seja outra questão?)

Comment: @Fernando Uma classe POCO é sua classe de domínio e um DTO é o objeto para transitar dados (podem possuir dados de mais de uma entidades), portanto não é POCO.

Comment: Renan, mas então se eu for na class POCO e colocar um DataAnnotation seja de validação ou mapeamento de ORM, o conceito original de POCO já caiu? Não é só a questão de referencia de tipos de dados. Não sei se fui claro?

Comment: @Fernando Construir uma classe POCO é escrever uma classe que não dependa de nada mais do que o próprio .Net Framework forneça. Se você usar DataAnnotation especifico para tecnologias como Mapeamento NH, Entity Framework, WCF, etc.., não estará usando POCO.

Answer (score 4):

### O que é POCO?

POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) assim como o POJO (Plain Old Java Object), de forma simples, significa um objeto que não possui nenhuma dependencia interna ou externa.

O termo é utilizado para identificar um objeto como um objeto simples, em detrimento aos objetos complexos e especializados que framework como ORMs geralmente utilizam.

### Porque utilizar POCO? Qual a vantagem que isso pode trazer?

- Permite um mecanismo simple de armazenamento de dados, e simplifica a
  serialização/passagem de dados entre camadas.
- Auxilia muito com a Injeção de Dependência e o padrão de projeto
  **Repository**
- Diminui a Complexidade e dependência entre outras camadas (As camadas
  que usam referenciam o POCO e o POCO não referencia nada) o que ajuda
  a diminuir o acoplamento
- Melhora a "testabilidade" pela simplificação

Referência: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object)

Comment: Utilizei sua definição de [tag:POCO], para especificar na tag que criei para perguntas relacionadas a esse conceito.

Comment: @Fernando. Vlw... que bom que pude ajudar