# Como selecionar o conteúdo de uma coluna vindo de um DataSet C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

Existe uma forma melhor de buscar o conteúdo de uma coluna especifica? Tenho uma informação que se repete em uma coluna “modelo” quero recupera este conteúdo apenas 1 vez. Estou fazendo assim, mais talvez tenha uma forma melhor de ser feito.

```
        public DataSet get()
        {
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Conexao.getConexao());
            conn.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select Codigo as Codigo, Nome as Nome,modelo, Cargo as Cargo, Empresa as Empresa From funcionarios", conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }

   private void exibirDados()
    {
        try
        {
            funcionarios funci = new funcionarios();
            DataSet ds = funci.get();
            dgvDados.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            string retorno = ConteudoColuna("modelo",ds);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private string ConteudoColuna(string nomeColuna, DataSet table)
    {
        DataTable recebeTable = table.Tables[0];

        foreach (DataColumn column in recebeTable.Columns)
        {

            if (column.ToString() == nomeColuna)
            {
                string teste2 = column.ToString();
                return column.ToString();
            }

        }
        return  "";
    }
```

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, fiz o ajuste da pergunta

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, isso e um exemplo para estudo, estou usando o .mdb

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, este codigo atual, me traz o nome da coluna, queria pegar o conteúdo de uma coluna especifica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Existe uma forma melhor de buscar o conteúdo de uma coluna especifica?

Sim, se você já tem o nome da coluna, basta fazer: `row["modelo"].ToString();` ou  poderia fazer apenas `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["modelo"].ToString();` que também funciona (desde que nenhuma coleção seja vazia), mas esse é o menor dos problemas...

O Primeiro passo é definir o que é um `Funcionario` em uma classe ["POCO"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/32905/69359):

```
public class Funcionario
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public string Modelo {get;set;}
}
```

Então, poderia fazer o seu Get, utilizando o objeto tipado:

```
public List<Funcionario> GetFuncionarios() //O Método retorna uma coleção de Funcionarios
{
    List<Funcionario> funcionarios = new List<Funcionario>();

    using (OleDbConnection conexao = new OleDbConnection("string conexao")) //utilizar uma conexão dentro de um bloco using, pra ser descartado após o bloco.
    {
        conexao.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select id, nome, modelo from funcionarios"))
        {
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) //O Data reader, vai lendo linha a linha e preenchendo a coleção. Se usar um DataAdapter com fill, ele primeiro seleciona tudo, e depois preenche o DataSet de uma vez (mais lento)
            {
                while (dr.Read()) //Enquanto estiver lendo...
                {
                    //vai adicionando funcionários...
                    funcionarios.Add(new Funcionario() 
                    { 
                       Id = dr.GetInt32(0),
                       Nome = dr.GetString(1),
                       Modelo = dr.GetString(2)
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }


    return funcionarios; //retorna a lista.

}
```

E depois, buscar/filtrar/exibir os dados:

```
//Selecionando todos os funcionários
List<Funcionario> funcionarios = d.GetFuncionarios();


//Selecionando um funcionário
Funcionario f1 = funcionarios.Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();


//Filtrando funcionários que começam com a letra A
List<Funcionario> filtrados = funcionarios.Where(x=> x.Nome.StartsWith("A")).ToList();


//Depois você pode usar essas lista como source do DataGridView:
//dataGridView1.DataSource = filtrados;

//Buscar apenas o Modelo do primeiro registro
string modelo = funcionarios.First().Modelo;
```

Apesar de não rodar (não tem base de dados), coloquei no [**SQLFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KzFlyh)

Comment: @itasouza, entendido ? alguma dúvida ?