# Listar itens além dos do banco de dados no Combobox em c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma aplicação em C# que realiza uma busca. Para isso é utilizado um campo chamado de 'status' que nada mais uma lista em um combobox. Preciso que apareça além dos status que vem do banco,  um status chamado 'TODOS' que não existe no banco, e se possível que ele fique por primeiro no combobox na hora de listar. Segue  meu código para listar os campos.

```
String string_conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexao"].ConnectionString;
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(string_conn);
      try
          {
            conn.Open();
           }
           catch (NpgsqlException sqle)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
           }
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
                dtResultado.Clear();
                da.Fill(dtResultado);

                Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    CbUsuario.DataSource = null;
                    CbUsuario.DataSource = dtResultado;
                    CbUsuario.ValueMember = "cod";
                    CbUsuario.DisplayMember = "nome";
                    CbUsuario.SelectedItem = "";
                    CbUsuario.Refresh();
                });
                conn.Close();
```

Comment: no `CbUsuario` que deseja adicionar o status "todos"?

Comment: primeiro, mostre como você está preenchendo o combo Status... depois dá uma olhada nessa resposta que acabei de colocar, você pode melhorar muito seu código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311774/69359 (no exemplo está com OleDb, mas tem todos as classes respectivas pra Npgsql)

Comment: isso, é para que quando eu for fazer uma consulta selecionando TODOS ele traga todos os resultados, ao contrario ele traz apenas o que esta selecionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Baseado nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11375314/6200920) do SO não é possível **adicionar diretamente** um novo item no combobox que é preenchido através do *DataSource*, para fazer isso terá que adicionar o item no objeto que está sendo feito o *binding*, no seu caso, adicionar no `DataTable`, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
String string_conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexao"].ConnectionString;
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(string_conn);
try
{
  conn.Open();
}
catch (NpgsqlException sqle)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Falha ao efetuar a conexão. Erro: " + sqle);
}
String sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario";
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
DataTable dtResultado = new DataTable();
dtResultado.Clear();
da.Fill(dtResultado);

//Adiciona uma linha com código 0 e texto "todos"
dtResultado.Rows.Add("0", "TODOS");

//Ordena por id o datatable
DataView view = dtResultado.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "cod ASC";
DataTable dtSorted = view.ToTable();

Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    CbUsuario.DataSource = null;
    CbUsuario.DataSource = dtResultado;
    CbUsuario.ValueMember = "cod";
    CbUsuario.DisplayMember = "nome";
    CbUsuario.SelectedItem = "";
    CbUsuario.Refresh();
});
conn.Close();
```

Para que o item "TODOS" apareça em primeiro, foi feita uma ordenação pela coluna **cod** do `DataTable`

Comment: Perfeito! Era o que eu precisava. Valeu Mestre.