# Dúvida C# Classe ADO.NET - Acessando dados de um DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, crud, ado.net

Olá, boa noite, sou novo por aqui e um iniciante na programação C#.

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema CRUD de discos de vinil (um vicio particular hahaha), utilizando classes ADO.NET, similar ao artigo abaixo. Entretanto não estou conseguindo avançar em meu projeto rs, estou tentando realizar uma pesquisar através do nome do álbum e ou do nome do artista/banda, através de um formulário, porém não estou conseguindo obter êxito em minha pesquisa.

Segue parte do meu projeto:

1) Classe ConsultaAlbum, onde retorna um DataTable.

```
class ConsultaAlbum
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

    public DataTable ConsultarAlbum(string pesquisaAlbum, string pesquisaArtista)
    {
        // Limpando os parãmetros
        dataAccess.LimparParametros();
        string SQL = @"SELECT 
                                       A.ID AS ID, 
                                       AR.ARTISTA AS ARTISTA, 
                                       GR.GRAVADORA AS GRAVADORA, 
                                       A.ALBUM AS ALBUM, 
                                       A.ANO AS ANO, 
                                       A.GENERO AS GENERO, 
                                       A.PRENSAGEM AS PRENSAGEM, 
                                       A.CORVINIL AS COR, 
                                       A.FORMATO AS FORMATO, 
                                       A.ROTACAO ROTACAO, 
                                       A.IMAGEM AS IMAGEM, 
                                       A.FLAG AS FLAG 
                       FROM 
                                       ALBUM AS A 
                                       INNER JOIN ARTISTA AS AR ON (A.ID_ARTISTA = AR.ID) 
                                       INNER JOIN GRAVADORA AS GR ON (A.ID_GRAVADORA = GR.ID)
                       WHERE 
                                       FLAG = 'A' AND 
                                       UPPER(ALBUM) LIKE '%@PESQUISA_ALBUM%' OR                                           
                                       UPPER(ARTISTA) LIKE'%@PESQUISA_ARTISTA%'";
        // Adicionando novos parâmetros
        dataAccess.AdicionarParametro("@PESQUISA_ALBUM", SqlDbType.VarChar, pesquisaAlbum);
        dataAccess.AdicionarParametro("@PESQUISA_ARTISTA", SqlDbType.VarChar, pesquisaArtista);
        // Retorna um DataTable com os dados da consulta
        return dataAccess.ExecutaConsulta(SQL);
    }

}
}
```

2)Botão Pesquisar, provavelmente aqui esta o meu problema, onde não estou conseguindo realizar a pesquisa, por não obter nenhum dado no DataTable, os dados vem de um retorno DataTable da classe acima, onde passo por parâmetro o nome do artista e ou do álbum, abaixo é um exemplo de como estou tentando realizar a pesquisa, através de um foreach e acessando suas linhas, apenas de como estou tentando realizar a pesquisa.

```
public partial class Consultar : UserControl
{
    DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess();

    public Consultar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
   private void btnPesquisarArtistaAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ConsultaAlbum consulta = new ConsultaAlbum();
        Album album = new Album();

        string pesquisaAlbum = "";
        string pesquisaArtista = "";

        pesquisaAlbum = txtPesquisarAlbum.Text;
        pesquisaArtista = txtPesquisarArtista.Text;

        //Pega os valores dos campos e seta nas propriedades das classes Artista, Gravadora e Album 
        consulta.ConsultarAlbum(pesquisaAlbum, pesquisaArtista);

        album.Artista = txtArtista.Text;
        txtAlbum.Text = album.NomeAlbum;
        txtGenero.Text = album.Genero;
        txtPrensagem.Text = album.Prensagem;
        txtGravadora.Text = album.Gravadora;
        //Tratar exceção!!
        //album.Ano = Convert.ToInt32(txtAno.Text);
        txtCor.Text = album.Cor;
        //Tratar exceção!!
        //(rButtonLp.Checked) ? "LP" : "EP" = album.Formato;
        //(rButton33.Checked) ? "33" : "45" = album.Rotacao;
        //Falta validar imagem em branco antes de salvar !!
        pictureVinyl.ImageLocation = album.Imagem;

    }

 }
}
```

3) Classe Album

```
class Album
{
[Required]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Nome do álbum obrigatório")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''''''''''''''''-''''''''\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\s]{1,100}$", ErrorMessage = "Nome inválido")]
public string NomeAlbum { get; set; }


[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''''''''''''''''-''''''''\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\s]{1,100}$", ErrorMessage = "Gênero inválido")]
public string Genero { get; set; }

[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9a-zA-Z''''''''''''''''-''''''''\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\s]{1,100}$", ErrorMessage = "Prensagem inválida")]
public string Prensagem { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Ano do álbum obrigatório")]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9'-'\s]{4,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Ano inválido")]
public int Ano { get; set; }

[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''''''''''''''''-''''''''\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\s]{1,100}$", ErrorMessage = "Cor inválida")]
public string Cor { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Formato { get; set; }

[Required]
public string Rotacao { get; set; }

public string Imagem { get; set; }

public string Flag { get; set; }

public string Artista { get; set; }


public string Gravadora { get; set; }

}
```

Estou desenvolvendo esse projeto de maneira autodidata, e aprendendo muito com o que pesquiso, cursos online, artigos e dúvidas publicadas aqui no site. 
Desde já, agradeço toda ajuda. obrigado =)

***Artigo utilizando para a criação da classe DataAccess ADO.NET:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/desenvolvendo-uma-classe-ado-net-para-acesso-a-dados-sql-server/32336

Comment: veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/311774/69359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que vejo a condição "WHERE" não me parece correcta.

Deveria estar "WHERE ... AND (... OR ...)"

```
 WHERE 
      A.FLAG = 'A' AND 
      (UPPER(A.ALBUM) LIKE '%@PESQUISA_ALBUM%' OR                                           
       UPPER(AR.ARTISTA) LIKE'%@PESQUISA_ARTISTA%')";
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o OR, pois quero pesquisar pelo campo artista ou album, um dos dois ou os dois, ao executar o SQL no BD, o mesmo me retorna normalmente os dados, por isso que acho que o SQL não esta errado, mas irei testar tua sugestão assim que estiver em casa. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente as cláusulas estão em conflito, use parâmetros para definir precedências quando houver `AND` e `OR` na mesma cláusula, caso contrário, o filtro do *FLAG* só funcionará em conjunto com o filtro do *ALBUM* mas não com o filtro do *ARTISTA*. Outro ponto importante é lembrar que em *SQL* a comparação de qualquer coisa com `NULL` retornará false. Então uma melhor escrita para a cláusula `WHERE` seria:

```
WHERE FLAG = 'A' AND (UPPER(ISNULL(ALBUM,'')) LIKE '%@PESQUISA_ALBUM%' OR                                       
  UPPER(ISNULL(ARTISTA,'')) LIKE '%@PESQUISA_ARTISTA%'")
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, irei implementar, desde já agradeço!